# Android build.xml Libraryproject

Tags: android, ant, build.xml

I have a `mainproject` that references an android library project.
My `mainproject` should be builded, optimized and obfuscated using Proguard. Therefore I used the buildscript described [here](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html). It's about 260 lines. Too much to post it here.

Now I've added a reference to a library project. My `default.properties` got changed with `android.library.reference.1=../RefProject`. Since I've added this my buildscript fails with the error:

> java.io.IOException: The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
>        [java]     at proguard.shrink.Shrinker.execute(Shrinker.java:148)
>        [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.shrink(ProGuard.java:275)
>        [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:101)
>        [java]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
>        [java] Note: there were 1 references to unknown classes.
>        [java]       You should check your configuration for typos.
>        [java] Ignoring unused library classes...
>        [java]   Original number of library classes: 2680
>        [java]   Final number of library classes:    9

Furthermore it would be cool if my library project will be optimized and obfuscated first and than used by the main project.

Is there a way to first build the library project (it has actually no build.xml) first and than use the builded apk (or is it a jar than?) in my mainproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ADT 14 all library projects should have their own `build.xml` files, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11302277/810368). All your library project will be build before your main project, in order specified in your `project.properties` file. More details about library project you can find in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects).