# Jenkins build of Android project with library

Tags: java, android, ant, jenkins

I have an android project that uses a library project. I have set my project.properties file to point to the library project, but when I run the ant build, I get:

/Users/zaphod/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: Invalid file: /Users/zaphod/.jenkins/jobs/participant/workspace/libraries/android-v7-support/appcompat/build.xml

This is blowing up in the subant task inside of build-setup. I have tried dropping a build.xml into this project and that didn't even change the error message. Based on some advice I found online, I created a project.properties file that contains android.library=true, but this didn't seem to help.

I have found several questions about this online, but can't seem to make heads or tails of the answers. Maybe this has changed in recent versions and these answers are obsolete, so I am posting in hopes of finding useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/Z2e3dY-3Ma0
which was referenced from here: [Adding android library project to an android project prevents Ant from building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236507/adding-android-library-project-to-an-android-project-prevents-ant-from-building)

Essentially, I needed to go into the library directory and run "android update lib-project" to create the build configuration files for that library. Once I'd done that, the builds ran smoothly.